# Hyper-V is disabled. I cannot run intelhaxm-android.exe - ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I don't know why this error has occured. I have looked at other similar questions and have followed all protocol needed.

I Know...

1. My computer supports VT-X or Intel Virtualization Technology
2. I have disabled Hyper-V in Windows Features
3. I have enabled VT-X for Intel in BIOS for my Dell XPS-13

I have tried everything but this does not work. Thanks in advance.

The following errors occur after I try running my emulator (Nexus 5x API 28):

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. These are the steps I gave someone else. I also enabled virtualization, but when I was following these steps and went back into BIOS, it was disabled again. Also, I noted that in Step 8, I tried to download the API 28 platform but it only came back as Partially Installed (no errors even). So I would also recommend trying to create a virtual device with a lower API, just to see if it being the newest is the issue.

1. Go into Android Studio and open the SDK Manager (under the Tools menu)
2. Under SDK Platforms tab, UNCHECK any boxes that are selected. If there are any boxes checked, that means they are installed - but we want to uninstall them for now.
3. Go to the SDK Tools tab. Make sure that Android Emulator, Android SDK Platform-Tools, and Android SDK Tools are all checked.
4. In the same tab, make sure that the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator is UNCHECKED. If it is checked, that means it is installed, but we want to uninstall it for now. (I also uninstalled Android SDK Build-Tools, but I'm not all sure if that step was necessary.)
5. Go to this link: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.2.0/haxm-windows_v7_2_0.zip    This is where we re-install the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator. Save it to your Downloads folder, and extract files. Do not launch any setup wizards yet!
6. Shut down your computer. As you start it up again, launch BIOS (For Windows 10, hold down F10 key). In BIOS, press the right arrow until you get to the third tab. Under there, go down to an option for Virtualization. If it is set as , use the Enter key to set it to . Press F10 to save and exit.
7. Go back into your Downloads folder, or wherever you saved the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (aka haxm). Double click on the file intelhaxm-android. This will install haxm to your computer.
8. Go into Android Studio, and open up the SDK Manager again. In the SDK Platforms tab, re-check the boxes for the APIs that you want. This will re-install them, since earlier we uninstalled them. (I tried to install API 28, but afterwards it was labeled Partially Installed, so I went ahead and downloaded APIs 27 and 26.) Click Apply and allow it/them to install.
9. Go to the tab SDK Tools and re-check the boxes for Android SDK Build-Tools and Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator. Click Apply and allow them to install.
10. At this point, I had already set up a Virtual Device with API 26, and it successfully loaded. Make sure that if you are setting up a Virtual Device, that you set it for an API that you installed in Step 8.

That was my solution, I hope it works for you!